# Is it possible to use the same power source for the arduino and a high current

Tags: power, current, transistor, atmega

I've need to control some leds which draw 300mA with an arduino (actually an atmega) and after some searching I think the following is the circuit I need, but I'm not really sure if the power source for the LEDs can be the same as for the arduino.[image]

R1 = 1k

Comment: Yes, it can, as long as it can provide the needed current. And be sure to not let the LED current through the Arduino. Connect the led circuit directly to your power supply

Answer (score 2):

If the power supply has sufficient power and voltage stability, you can use it to power the LED and Arduino. However, the circuit is not entirely correct on the LED side, a current limiting resistor should be used in series with the LED. I would also recommend using a more powerful bipolar transistor or field effect transistor.

Comment: Thank you, yes, the leds have a resistor connected I just didn't draw it, didn't realize it could be confusing for someone seeing it.
Thanks for the tip on the transtor, what would be the problem with this one?

Comment: This transistor will dissipate about 0.2 W of power and may be slightly warm.

Comment: can you use a npn transistor high side like that from the MCU? IT would seem to be a voltage follower, 0.6v below Vcc. Much better to switch on the low side...